# Issue with loop iteration: "too many indices for array"

Tags: python, nested-loops, ode

I have code written that discretizes a PDE and solves it using finite difference method

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
#number of discretization points
n = 100
#length of bar (1D object/surface)
L = 0.1
#make a vector containing location of each discretization point 
X = np.linspace(0, L, n)

h = L/(n - 1)

kappa = 2*10**(-9)
def odefunc(T, t):
    dTdt = np.zeros(X.shape)
    dTdt[0] = 0
    dTdt[-1] = 0
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        dTdt[i] = (kappa/h**2) * (T[i+1]- 2*T[i] + T[i -1])/h**2
    return dTdt
init = 0*np.ones(X.shape)
init[0] = 0.01
init[-1] = 0
tt = np.linspace(0.0, 1.2, 100).round(3)
sol = odeint(odefunc, init, tt)
sol[0] = 0
```

I am trying to extend this to a 2D case and am trying to use the meshgrid method to create a grid since using a 2D array doesn't seem to be helping me. I have the following thus far:

```
#length of surface 
L = 0.1
#height of surface
ht = 0.1

nx,ny = (100,100)
x = np.linspace(0,L,nx)
y = np.linspace(0,ht,ny)
#make a grid containing location of each discretization point 
X,Y = np.meshgrid (x,y)
#h = L/(n - 1)
#print(h)

def odefunc(T, t):
 dTdt = np.zeros_like(X)

 dTdt[0][0] = 0
 dTdt[0][-1] = 0
 dTdt[-1][0] = 0
 dTdt[-1][-1] = 0
 Txx = np.zeros((100,100))
 print(Txx)
 Tyy = np.zeros((100,100))
 for i in range(1, nx-1):
     for j in range(1,ny-1):
         Txx = (T[i+1,j] - 2*T[i,j] + T[i-1,j])
         Tyy = (T[i,j+1]-2*T[i,j]+T[i,j-1])
         dTdt[i][j] = Txx + Tyy
 print(dTdt)
 return dTdt
```

This throws the error, IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Note: I have left off the ODE solver part for the 2D case and ignored some constants as I am getting started. Do I need to define T itself as I did DTdt in the first line of the function as well? Any other suggestions?

I have tried modeling the second code after the first but the extra iteration is causing issues.

---

IGNORE ABOVE THIS LINE

So I think I have a solution for this now:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
#number of discretization points
n = 100
#length of surface (1D object/surface)
L = 0.1
#height of surface
ht = 0.1
#
nx,ny = (100,100)
dTdt = np.zeros((nx,ny))
#make a matrix containing location of each discretization point 
dx = L/nx
dy = ht/ny
#h = L/(n - 1)
#print(h)


def odefunc(T, t):
    magnitude = 2
    selection = 'uniform'
    nx,ny = (100,100)


    dTdt = np.zeros((nx,ny))
    #dTdt[0,0] = 0
    #dTdt[0,-1] = 0
    #dTdt[-1,0] = 0
    #dTdt[-1,-1] = 0
    T = np.zeros((100,100))
    input = np.zeros((100,100))
    for i in range(1, nx-1):
        for j in range(1,ny-1):
            Txx = (T[i+1,j] - 2*T[i,j] + T[i-1,j])/(dx**2)
            Tyy = (T[i,j+1]-2*T[i,j]+T[i,j-1])/(dy**2)
            input = 2
            dTdt[i,j] = Txx + Tyy +input
            #print(dTdt[i,j])
    result = dTdt.flatten() 

    return result

init = np.zeros((nx,ny))
inituse = init.flatten()
#init[0:100] = 5
#for z in range(1,100):
   # init[z*100] = 5
#for l in range(1,100):
   # init[l*100+99] = 5
#init[9901:10000] = 5

tt = np.linspace(0.0, 1.2, 100).round(3)
sol = odeint(odefunc, inituse, tt)



discretesol = sol.reshape(100,100,100)





for k in range(0, len(tt), 2):

        x = np.linspace(0,L,nx)
        y = np.linspace(0,ht,ny)
        X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        Z = discretesol[:,:,k]
        
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
        plt.show()
```

All initial conditions for every discretization point (and thus the boundary conditions) are 0. The heat PDE allows for input and it just an additive term. Thus, I tried to implement this, but for some reason, despite the input being constant and uniform, I only see a temperature response at one of the boundaries. If you delete this input, then of course nothing happens and the entire distribution stays at 0 the whole time.

[Plot showing ramp distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMDAN.png)

To be clear the equation I am implementing is this but the 2D version. [Heat Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isldB.png)

Edit 2: Here is what the new plot looks like:

[Plot after changing T initialization to empty and not zeros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdu87.png)

Another example:

[Another Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNoXM.png)

Comment: Which line does it throw the error on?

Comment: @AndrewMorton on the Txx line (edit: the Txx line inside the for loop). Also, I just update the code attached and the associated error because I realized I forgot to making an update before attaching the code. I think you commented after I edited, but just making sure. I am confused why it is saying the array is 1-dimensional when I even explicitly defined it as a 2d array with the np.zeros command

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and assuming that you are calling the new 2D `odefunc` with the same six lines of initialization as in the first 1D example (not criticizing, just the 2D example doesn't have `T` initialized). If so, `T` will be initialized as a 1D array and give you an indexing error on that line; maybe this is the issue?

Comment: Looking at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/10l4t6m/comment/j5vcjsw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) code, it does in fact seem like `T`  is initialized as a 1D array: `init = 0*np.ones(nx*ny)`

Comment: Correct, I have figured out most of the code now (maybe I should reupload) however I am now just having issues with boundary conditions and things like that.

Comment: If you update the question into a few bullet points, I can try to answer :)

Comment: @MattMorse Just update, I drew a line as to be clear of where remaining questions lie. I can also embed the code directly here, but I figured Colab may be easier if you want to quickly run it and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Just don't have Colab access and I think SO prefers code snippets and images embedded in the post, if it's not too much trouble to update the post again. Are you saying that you are solving the normal heat equation with a constant source over the whole domain? It would also help if you can write down the formula you are trying to solve explicitly.

Comment: @MattMorse Okay, I embedded the code and everything and you should be able to see it now. Also, wrote down all the other relevant information.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for clarifying the problem. I think as a first step, we need to rule out a plotting error (I always make mistakes using the 3D tools in matplotlib). I would recommend changing the plots to use `imshow` and visualize the solution as a heatmap, since this accepts a 2D array as input and there will be fewer surprises.

Comment: Once you are confident that what you are seeing visually is consistent with the output of the code (maybe check a few values for a sanity check), the next step is to isolate the source of the numerical issues that you are seeing. The next thing I would do is verify that your spatial finite difference scheme is correct and that it works without the added forcing term.

Comment: You can do this two ways: (1) solve a time-independent problem like Poisson's equation and remove `odeint` from consideration; (2) `odefunc` computes an approximate derivative of the solution at time t, so if you know the true derivative, you can compare `odefunc(T,t) - true_grad(T,t)` and as you increase the number grid points, you should see the error decrease (only to a certain point, then the error will increase again)

Comment: Also, iIt looks like LeVeque's book is available for free: https://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/fdmbook/

Comment: @MattMorse Thank you for this! I think that the plotting is fine. This is because if I look at an Excel file, there are some weird values that show up, and some cells are empty. I will move onto maybe trying to solve Poisson's equation. One other thing though, in the 1D case, you see there is dTdt[0] = 0 and dTdt[-1] = 0. Again, this code was given to me and I am trying to expand it, but are these just for initializing the loop? If they are boundary conditions, that would make sense but can Neumann boundary conditions be a derivative in terms of time and not space?

Comment: Well I think I may see why it is done that way. It seems that setting the initial conditions as T[0] = 0.1 and T [-1] = 0, and then setting dT/dt[0] = 0, and dTdt[-1] = 0, the dTdt statements themselves are not boundary conditions but since you have initial values and then you fix the derivatives at those points this is equivalent to having Dirichlet BCs at location 0 and -1 because the initial T values won't ever change.

Comment: @pythonengineer I'm tempted to say that this is error. If you look at the first three lines of `odefunc()` in 1D, you see that `dTdt = np.zeros(X.shape)`, i.e. it is already initialized to 0. The following two lines don't actually change anything about `dTdt` in 1D so interpreting them too carefully and trying to extrapolate to 2D might be misleading.

Comment: Some quick Googling turned up [this worked out example](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/solving-2d-heat-equation-numerically-using-python-3334004aa01a). It doesn't use `odeint` so I think it might be more informative since all the working pieces are stripped out. There is also some basic outline of the formulas involved. I think it would be very much worth your time to work through this blog post, understand the various pieces, and most importantly, try to correct your code based on the working code there (they aren't exactly the same so the exercise will hopefully be instructive).

Comment: A couple comments about the linked implementation: 1. it is slow because it explicitly loops over grid points in Python. This will be punishing. If you end up using this implementation in some form, re-write the spatial loops over the 2D grid using the slicing notation on lines 33-36, which vectorizes these ops. 2. once you understand this code clearly, you should be able to add the now-vectorized loops back into `odeint` and solve with a superior implicit solver from scipy instead of the explicit euler step they use there.

Comment: I don't think that that would be the issue. If you look at my code I am not really trying to copy that from the 1D case as I have dTdt set to 0 as well and have nothing after it inside the function and still get instability. I have looked at that link. Basically, the main difference is the way they are discretizing spatially, which after discussing with some others, I don't think that matters too much.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not report how you solved the first stated problem, and what the errors were:

- The interface of `odeint` requires that the first argument in the ODE function (as well as the initial value) is a 1D array  (or a scalar). Correspondingly the output should also be such an array.

Thus the frame for the ODE function should be

```
T = T.reshape((nx,ny))
dTdt = np.zeros_like(T)
...
return dTdt.flatten()
```

You are  not using the full power of numpy. Replace the loops with

```
Txx = (T[2:,1:-1]-2*T[1:-1,1:-1]+T[:-2,1:-1])/(dx**2)
Tyy = (T[1:-1,2:]-2*T[1:-1,1:-1]+T[1:-1,:-2])/(dy**2)
dTdt[1:-1,1:-1] = Txx + Tyy + 2
```

---

It is of course very unhelpful if you zero out `T` before use like in the reddit code fragment.

---

The output of `odeint` is a list of state vectors, the first index is for the position of the state vector in the list. So the simultaneous transformation is `sol_grid = sol.reshape((-1,nx,ny))`, the first dimension computed automatically. Then access `Z = sol_grid[k]`. Or reshape on-the-fly `Z = sol[k].reshape((nx,ny))`.

Comment: I think the main issue was using the meshgrid instead of normal 2D arrays (for the calculations at least). I'm not sure specifically what about that caused the problem, but using 2D arrays made it easier. Could you explain what the bad effects of zeroing out T before use would be?

Comment: Just adding on here, I can also initialize T with np.empty((100,100)), right?

Comment: `T` is the input variable. If you zero it out, you lose all information on the dynamics. // The `meshgrid` returns two 2D arrays, where do you see this differently? // There exists the `odeintw` package, essentially a wrapper around `odeint`, that works with matrix-valued states.

Comment: Right, which is what I thought, but for some reason I think it was thinking that Txx and Tyy were 1D still, even though I defined them as 2D. It shouldn't matter though because I think if you look above (I edited the post to include modified code), it runs. However, the plots just don't look right. Do I need to use the odeintw package though? Is there an inherent issue with flattening out the array and solving the ODEs and then reshaping?

Comment: You have a mental blockade. At the moment you compute the Laplacian of a zero array, not of the current state array. //No, it is not necessary to use odeintw, that just automates the wrapping construction.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by mental blockade in this case. I understand I cannot have a zero array. I have updated this and also set the dTdt array to be initially empty as well. I am still seeing some weird resulting plots, perhaps due to some kind of numerical instability (I attached a new one at the end of the post). I can update the code again, but it is the same just with those changes.

Comment: Also, just to emphasize what the current issue is, I am getting errors like this too "at t (=r1) and step size h (=r2), the    
       corrector convergence failed repeatedly " which obviously sounds like a convergence error but I don't know where to start to solve this.

Comment: Actively set the error tolerances, the defaults might not be suitable for high-dimensional problems. The package might not be suitable for high dimensions, use one where you can select a sparse linear algebra and provide the sparse Jacobian. But my corrected version has a long integration run time, but goes trough and converges in one step to the limit shape. // I'll add a remark on the output format in the answer.

Comment: Okay sorry, I am having trouble trying to follow where the different pieces of what you're saying is connected. The code you added to the answer is just reformatting, does this have anything to do with the first part of what you just commented? Basically, reformatting like that doesn't have anything to do with setting error tolerances, changing to the sparse linear algebra, so I am trying to be clear on what its purpose is. Also, why does changing this have anything to do with the run time?

Comment: I implemented the changes you listed in the remark, but I am still curious what those will help with. I am still seeing errors like "/var/folders/6p/7bq639bj0p3c244v6_z0wl7h0000gn/T/ipykernel_38491/3486452969.py:37: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  Txx = (T[i+1,j] - 2*T[i,j] + T[i-1,j])/(dx**2)" and much more I am just leaving them out. I am assuming these have to do with the first part of your last comment though, namely that I need to set error tolerances and using a different package or something and the code changes in your post don't address that.